# Sigma-Omega model on curved space-time

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime, sigma-models

I'm trying to get the equations of motion for the scalar meson $\sigma$, vector meson field $\omega_{\mu}$ and finally for the nucleons $\Psi=(\Psi_n,\Psi_p)^{T}$ in the sigma omega model on a curved space-time. In particular I'm trying to do it with the Tolmann-Oppenheimer-Volkoff metric:
$$ds^{2}=-e^{2\nu(r)}dt^{2}+{(1-\frac{2m(r)}{r})}^{-1}dr^{2}+r^{2}d\Omega^{2}$$

Where:
$$\frac{d\nu}{dr}=\frac{(m(r)+4\pi r^{3}p(r))}{r(r-2m(r))}  ; \qquad\frac{dm}{dr}=4\pi r^{2}\varepsilon(r).$$

The lagrangian in minkowski space-time is:

$$\mathcal{L}=\bar{\Psi}[(i\gamma^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu}+ig_{\omega}\omega_{\mu})-(m-g_{\sigma}\sigma)]\Psi + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\sigma \partial^{\mu}\sigma-m_{\sigma}^{2}\sigma^{2})-\frac{1}{4}\omega^{\mu\nu}\omega_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}m_{\omega}^{2}\omega^{\mu}\omega_{\mu}.$$

So now i change partial derivatives for covariant ones,in the lagrangian i have to add $\sqrt{-g}$, to the scalar field add the curvature term coupled to the sigma field, and contracted indices should be carried out throguh the metric. So it turns out to be:

$\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{-g}\{\bar{\Psi}[i\gamma^{\mu}(\nabla_{\mu}+ig_{\omega}\omega_{\mu})-(m-g_{\sigma}\sigma)]\Psi + \frac{1}{2}(g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\sigma \nabla^{\nu}\sigma-m_{\sigma}^{2}\sigma^{2})-\xi R \sigma^{2}-\frac{1}{4}g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}\omega_{\alpha\beta}\omega_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}m_{\omega}^{2}g^{\mu\nu}\omega_{\nu}\omega_{\mu}\}$

Where $\nabla_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}e^{\beta}_{k}(\partial_{\mu}e_{\beta h})S^{hk}$, being $S^{hk}=\frac{1}{2}[\gamma^{h},\gamma^{k}]$ and $e^{\mu}_{\nu}$ tetrads

In this case of a diagonal metric i think I'm able to choose them this way:
$e^{t}_{t}=e^{\nu}dt$ ; $e^{r}_{r}={(1-\frac{2m}{r})}^{-\frac{1}{2}}dr$ ; $e^{\theta}_{\theta}=rd\theta$ ; $e^{\phi}_{\phi}=rsin(\theta)d\phi$
Now i wish to get to the equations of motion with euler lagrange equations:

$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}-\nabla_{\mu}(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\nabla_{\mu}\phi)})=0$
Once i get the equations i have a problem. I'm doing something wrong becuase the covariant derivative is exactly the same to the partial one, and i think is because of the selection of the tetrads makes that $S^{hk}=0$. Some help would be nice, any correction or comentary, thanks.